# replace first character of each line in file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-manipulation

I am trying to replace some of the first characters in lines from multiple txt files and have this code but the output is wrong:

```
for filename in glob.glob('./labels/**/*.txt', recursive=True):
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    original_lines = f.readlines()
with open(filename, 'w') as out:
    for line in original_lines:
        if line.startswith('0'):
            line0 = line
            out.write(line0)
        if line.startswith('1'):
            line1 = line
            out.write(line1)
        if line.startswith('2'):
            line2 = line
            out.write(line2)
        if line.startswith('3'):
            line3 = line
            out.write(line3)
        if line.startswith('5'):
            line4 = '4' + line[1:]
            out.write(line4)
        if line.startswith('7'):
            line5 = '5' + line[1:]
            out.write(line5)
        if line.startswith('9'):
            line6 = '6' + line[1:]
            out.write(line6)
        if line.startswith('10'):
            line7 = '7' + line[1:]
            out.write(line7)
        if line.startswith('11'):
            line8 = '8' + line[1:]
            out.write(line8)
        if line.startswith('12'):
            line9 = '9' + line[1:]
            out.write(line9)
```

So if I have a file like this:

0 0.2 0.4 0.8

12 0.1 0.1 0.25

7 0.66 0.80 0.91

I want output to be:

0 0.2 0.4 0.8

9 0.1 0.1 0.25

5 0.66 0.80 0.91

Comment: If a line starts with '12' both .startswith('1') and .startswith('12') will be true which could explain part of your issues.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the problems,I solved it by using line.split(' '), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some slicing issues for example lets say your input is `12 0.1 0.1 0.25` `line[1:]` is going to be  `2 0.1 0.1 0.25` because your input is a string. You can use something like:

```
line = '12 0.1 0.1 0.25'.split(' ') #convert your string to a list

temp = int(line[0]) #get first element and convert to integer to make comparisons easier

if temp < 3:
    print(' '.join(line))
elif temp == 5: 
    line[0] = '4'
    print(' '.join(line))
elif temp == 7:
    line[0] = '5'
    print(' '.join(line))
elif temp > 8:
    line[0] =str(temp - 3)
    print(' '.join(line))

#Output: 

9 0.1 0.1 0.25
```

Note: It's better to use `elif` instead of `if` in your case because if one of your conditions are true it is not going to check rest of the conditions. More info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I posted I saw that it would slice bad and I solved it using line.split(' ')